# How to Integrate Ckeditor on angular2 webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack, ckeditor, jhipster, webpack-2

I am trying to integrate ckeditor with angular2 in my jhipster genereted project but no luck.

There is a lot of examples and instructions regarding integration of ckeditor with angular2 but i'm stuck on where to put **System.config** on jhipster as per [this](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor) instruction.

Thank you,

Comment: JHipster uses webpack not systemjs, so System.config is useless. See https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/54

Comment: Hi! @GaëlMarziou thanks for your very important feedback, now I understand jhipster is using webpack.Can you please point out me the integration of ckeditor with webpack? because I've checked your preferred link and I quite lost there.

Comment: Sorry I don't use ckeditor so I can't help more